# C++ How to let user determine array size?

Tags: c++, arrays

My program allows a user to enter 50 numbers and gives the total and average. My array size is a constant set at 50. I want the user to be able to enter no more than 50 numbers but have  the option to enter less. My idea would be to to enter 'q' to quit to stop prompting user for a number. How would I do that?

```js
for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++) {
  cout << "Enter Number: ";
  cin >> array[i];
}
```

Comment: Even if the array is limited to 50 you can accept less - Your idea to enter q is good but I don't understand what help you need when you say "how would I do that"?  Just accept the input as a string, check it for q and then convert it to a number and store it.

Comment: I need help adding enter 'q' to my existing for loop

Comment: What happens to your code now when you enter something that isn't a number?

Comment: You need to `cin >> ` to a string and then check it against `q` if it is equal break the loop or if its not try to convert to a number (presumably `int`) and stick it in the array.

Comment: You don't need an array to store every numbers just to calculate average. Only sum and count is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to input a string and then check if the string is q before you convert it to a number:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    const int ARRAY_SIZE=50;
    int array[ARRAY_SIZE];
    std::string temp;
    int items;

    for(items=0; items<ARRAY_SIZE; items++){
        std::cout << "Enter Number: ";
        std::cin >> temp;
        if(temp=="q" || temp=="Q") break;
        array[items] = atoi(temp.c_str());
    }

    std::cout << items << " items entered:\n";
    std::copy(array, array+items, std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout,"\n"));

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
int ARRAY_SIZE = 0;
for(int i=0; i < 50; i++){
    cout << "Enter Number: ";
    cin >> array[i];
    if(array1[i] == 'q')
       break;
    ARRAY_SIZE++;
}
int* array2 = new int[ARRAY_SIZE];
for(int i=0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++
    array2[i] = array[i];
```

...then delete array1. This should work, that way the user determines the size of the array2, with a maximum of 50, but variable, size.

Hope this helps, this is my first answer, so if it's bad I am sorry.

Comment: If the type of `array1` is `int` then entering a letter 'q' won't work.